# Compare Two Names and Return Results That Are Different By X Characters

Tags: oracle, compare, names

I have two tables with the same structure that I am comparing, MN1 and MN2. Both tables contain a column called onmfirst which contains a name.
I am trying to write a query that will compare the first names and only select records that are different, specifically only return names 
that don't match and are off by at least the first 3 characters.

The query is current running a simple **"mn1.onmfirst <> mn2.onmfirst**". This of course will display records that don't match and doesn't take 
into consideration the name may be the same and just shortened.

For example:

RETURNED/EXPECTED RESULTS

- John vs Adam
- Steven vs Liam
- Lisa vs Sandra

NOT RETURNED/OMITTED

- John vs Johnathan
- Jim vs Jimmy
- Greg vs Gregory

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just compare substrings!

```
substr(mn1.onmfirst, 1,3) <> substr(mn2.onmfirst, 1,3)
```